# Strange definition of $H_0(X)$, the zeroth singular homology group

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm studying singular homology, and found some strange thing in the definition.
(All I have as backrounds are some basic definitions and facts about singular homology.)

The strange thing is the **zeroth boundary map** $\partial_0 :C_0(X)\to C_{-1}(X)$ which is defined to be mere a trivial map. It is well-known that this definition leads to the fact that $H_0(X)$ has all the path components of $X$ as its free abelian basis. This is really not bad since the topological information about path connectedness is transformed into an algebraic stuff.

**Summary of this post**.
I think it is unnatural for $\partial_0$ to be trivial. What if $C_{-1}(X)=\mathbb Z$ and $\partial_0$ *sums up* all the coeffficients of a $0$-chain? Is there any useful homology theory like this?

For simplicity let's see what happens in affine case. Then we may regard $\partial$ as an antiderivation of degree $-1$ on a certain graded $\mathbb Z$-associative unital algebra, a noncommutative multivariate polynomial ring over integers.

The awkwardness appears when I try to compute the boundary of an **affine $p$-simplex** $v=v_0 \cdots v_p$ in a convex set $K$ containing all $v_i$'s in a Euclidean space.

To explain my point I fix some definitions I used:

This notation is not standard, but $v_0 \cdots v_p$ stands just for the affine map of $\Delta_p$ onto the convex hull of $v_0,\cdots,v_p$ sending the origin $e_0$ to $v_0$, $e _1$ to $v_1$, $\cdots$, and $e _p$ to $v_p$. Here $\Delta_p\subset\mathbb R ^p$ contains the origin as a vertex. For $i\ge 1$, the $i$-th entry of $e_i$ is $1$, and others are $0$.

The **boundary** $\partial v=\partial (v_0\cdots v_p)$ of $v_0\cdots v_p$ is defined to be an affine $(p-1)$-chain by the formal sum
$$\sum_{i=0} ^p (-1)^i v_0\cdots \hat{v}_i\cdots v_p,$$
where hat means omission. Being aware that $e_0 \cdots \hat{e}_i \cdots e_p$ is the **$i$-th face map** $F_i^p$, we may also write
$$\partial v = \sum_{i=0}^p (-1)^i v\circ F_i^p,$$
which shows my definition is same as the ordinary one.

Being the one-term sum of the empty product, *the boundary of an affine $0$-simplex equals the integer $1$*. So I define $\partial v_0 = 1$. This is the difference with the ordinary one.

The notation $A_p(K)$ stands for **the $p$-th affine chain group** of $K$ for each $p\ge 0$, the free abelian group with its basis all the affine $p$-simplexes in $K$. Let $A_{-1}(K)=\mathbb Z$. Defining $\partial_p$ to be the restriction of $\partial$ to $A_p(K)$, we get a chain complex
$$ \cdots \to A_3(K) \to A_2(K) \to A_1(K) \to A_0(K) \to A_{-1}(K) \to 0 \to \cdots .$$

With some easy computation, One can construct a graded $\mathbb Z$-algebra $A_*(K)=\oplus_{i=-1}^{\infty}A_i(K)$ which has $\partial$ as an antiderivation of degree $-1$. The product in this algebra is determined by the formula
$$(v_0\cdots v_p)(w_0\cdots w_q) = v_0\cdots v_p w_0 \cdots w_q$$
which defines the product of basis elements as concatenation.
The verification is a routine using the freeness.

Here is a convenience of defining $\partial_0$ as I did: The product rule. For any affine $p$- and $q$-chains $\alpha$ and $\beta$, we have
$$\partial(\alpha\beta)=(\partial\alpha)\beta+(-1)^{p+1}\alpha\partial\beta.$$
In particular, for an affine 2-chain we can now compute as below:
$$\partial(v_0v_1)=(\partial v_0)v_1-v_0\partial v_1=v_1-v_0,$$
since $\partial v_0 = \partial v_1 = 1$.

But many authors define $\partial_0$ to be trivial. I don't think this is useful since it is hard to use $H_0(X)$ to compute the number of path components of $X$; rather the converse can we do. So I think we can discard the ordinary $H_0(X)$ without fear.

I didn't make any computations about singular homology case yet, but I expect there would also be some convenience to define $\partial_0$ a *coefficient summing-up* function.

Is there any homology theory with this *summing-up* function?

Thank you.

Comment: Your new definition of $\partial_0$ _extends_ the chain complex. The homology of this new chain complex is the reduced homology.

Comment: @feynhat Why not an official answer?

Comment: What exactly $C_{-1}(X)$ is? A singular $n$-simplex is only well defined for $n\geq 0$. Is $C_{-1}(X)=\mathbb{Z}$ by definition? I wonder where exactly such definition is given?

Comment: @freakish I believe the idea is that a -1 simplex should be the empty set, and the boundary of any 0 simplex is the empty set, so extending linearly you get the boundary is the sum of coefficients.